# Assets/Script/C2.cs(16,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Tags: unity-game-engine, project

ive been trying to make a piano work on unity, im also new at this and ive been getting this error.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class C2 : MonoBehaviour {

  public AudioSource C2;

    private void OnMouseDown()
  {
      C2.play();

  }
        
    }
there is the code but cant find the problem
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change the "public class C2 :" to "public class PianoC2 :" And then change the script name in the assets folder also to "PianoC2" cause the class name should everytime be the same as the scripts name in the assets folder :)

Also, Is your sound working? Cause i think you need to add "using UnityEngine.Audio;" at the top if it ain't working.